# The arguments are not passed into the function correctly

Tags: r

RStudio Ver: Version 1.0.143

Windows Ver: Windows10 Pro

I'm writing a function to return the requested hospital in each state.

The structure of the function is like this: rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best")

`outcome` is the standard to order the result, and `num` tells the function the rank to choose.

The function can return the right result with `num = "best"` and `other numeric numbers`, but cannot give the right result with `"worst"`. The code of the function is like this:

```
    rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {
            ## Read outcome data
            datful <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
            ## Check that state and outcome are valid
            if(outcome == "heart attack"){
                    oc <- 11
                    } else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
                            oc <- 17
                            } else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
                                    oc <- 23
                            } else {
                                    "invalid outcome"
                            }
            ## For each state, find the hospital of the given rank
            StaUni <- unique(datful[,7])
            StaUni <- sort(StaUni)
            sta_req <- c()
            hos_req <- c()
            out_req <- c()
            for(i in StaUni){
                    ##For each state, assemble a data.frame
                    good <- datful[, 7] == i  
                    Sta_i <- datful[, 7][good]
                    Hos_i <- datful[, 2][good]
                    Out_i <- as.numeric(datful[, oc][good])
                    out_na <- is.na(Out_i)
                    Sta_i <- Sta_i[!out_na]
                    Hos_i <- Hos_i[!out_na]
                    Out_i <- Out_i[!out_na]
                    Obs_i <- data.frame(Sta_i, Hos_i, Out_i)
                    ##Reoder each data.frame
                    Obs_i <- Obs_i[order(Obs_i[, 3], Obs_i[, 2]),]
                    ## Change the value of num depend on it's value.
                    if(num == "best"){
                            num = 1
                    } else if(num == "worst"){
                                    num = sum(good)
                            } else {
                                            num = num
                                    }
                    hos_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[num, 2])
                    sta_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[num, 1])
                    out_req[i] <- as.numeric(Obs_i[num, 3])
            }
            ## Return a data frame with the hospital names and the
            ## (abbreviated) state name
            DFReq <- cbind(hos_req, sta_req)
            DFReq
    }
```

The result is like this:

```
>tail(rankall("pneumonia", "worst"), 3)
   hos_req                               sta_req
WI "MINISTRY DOOR COUNTY MEDICAL CENTER" "WI"   
WV "MONTGOMERY GENERAL HOSPITAL, INC"    "WV"   
WY "EVANSTON REGIONAL HOSPITAL"          "WY"   
There were 46 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

To see where the problem is, I tried to give `"pneumonia"` to `outcome`, and `"worst"` to `num`. Everything else is left like the function(except it is not a function, I'm only want to see where the problem could be). The code is like this:

```
        ## Read outcome data
        datful <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
        ## Check that state and outcome are valid

        ## For each state, find the hospital of the given rank
        StaUni <- unique(datful[,7])
        StaUni <- sort(StaUni)
        sta_req <- c()
        hos_req <- c()
        out_req <- c()
        for(i in StaUni){
                ##For each state, assemble a data.frame
                good <- datful[, 7] == i  
                Sta_i <- datful[, 7][good]
                Hos_i <- datful[, 2][good]
                Out_i <- as.numeric(datful[, 23][good])
                out_na <- is.na(Out_i)
                Sta_i <- Sta_i[!out_na]
                Hos_i <- Hos_i[!out_na]
                Out_i <- Out_i[!out_na]
                Obs_i <- data.frame(Sta_i, Hos_i, Out_i)
                ##Reoder each data.frame
                Obs_i <- Obs_i[order(Obs_i[, 3], Obs_i[, 2]),]
                ## Change the value of num depend on it's value.

                hos_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[length(Sta_i), 2])
                sta_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[length(Sta_i), 1])
                out_req[i] <- as.numeric(Obs_i[length(Sta_i), 3])
        }
        ## Return a data frame with the hospital names and the
        ## (abbreviated) state name
        DFReq <- cbind(hos_req, sta_req)
        DFReq
```

The last 3 lines of the result is like this(which is the right answer):

```
WI "MAYO CLINIC HEALTH SYSTEM - NORTHLAND, INC"  "WI"   
WV "PLATEAU MEDICAL CENTER"                      "WV"   
WY "NORTH BIG HORN HOSPITAL DISTRICT"            "WY"
```

Anyone can tell me what to change to make the function work when `num = "worse"`?

For anyone want to run the codes, here's the data:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1174148/outcome-of-care-measures.csv

Comment: @ChiPak Just like what I thought, your solution doesn't work. False is 0, and True is 1, so sum(good) will be the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ryan If you solved your own question, post it as an answer instead of editing in the body of the question. This will help future readers to find the solution.

Comment: @Llopis I didn't find my answer, the second part is not a function, I just put the test value of the argument inside the function, so that it calculate the answer of a test value, which works fine. but if I use the function with the test value, the result is wrong.

Comment: @ChiPak There's no exit of the function.

Comment: Okay, you're not getting the same answer because in your function `rankall` you use `num` for two variables. `num` is used as a character argument `num="best"` initially. `if(num == "worst")` changes `num` to `sum(good)`. Next time through the iteration, `num == sum(good)` which assigns `num = num`. Just change one of the `num` and you should get the same answer.

Comment: @ChiPak I think before num get it number, it will go through the judgement first. And I tried  num_2 == sum(good) and num_2 = num, which still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our exchange in the Comments. This should give you the same answer:

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = "best") {
        ## Read outcome data
        datful <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
        ## Check that state and outcome are valid
        if(outcome == "heart attack"){
                oc <- 11
                } else if(outcome == "heart failure"){
                        oc <- 17
                        } else if(outcome == "pneumonia"){
                                oc <- 23
                        } else {
                                "invalid outcome"
                        }
        ## For each state, find the hospital of the given rank
        StaUni <- unique(datful[,7])
        StaUni <- sort(StaUni)
        sta_req <- c()
        hos_req <- c()
        out_req <- c()
    V <- 1
        for(i in StaUni){
                ##For each state, assemble a data.frame
                good <- datful[, 7] == i  
          # print(tail(good))
                Sta_i <- datful[, 7][good]
                Hos_i <- datful[, 2][good]
                Out_i <- as.numeric(datful[, oc][good])
                out_na <- is.na(Out_i)
                Sta_i <- Sta_i[!out_na]
                Hos_i <- Hos_i[!out_na]
                Out_i <- Out_i[!out_na]
                Obs_i <- data.frame(Sta_i, Hos_i, Out_i)
                ##Reoder each data.frame
                Obs_i <- Obs_i[order(Obs_i[, 3], Obs_i[, 2]),]
                print(tail(Obs_i))
                ## Change the value of num depend on it's value.
                if(num == "best"){
                        V <- 1
                } else if(num == "worst"){
                                V <- length(Sta_i)
                        } else {
                                        V <- V
                                }
                hos_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[V, 2])
                sta_req[i] <- as.character(Obs_i[V, 1])
                out_req[i] <- as.numeric(Obs_i[V, 3])
        }
        ## Return a data frame with the hospital names and the
        ## (abbreviated) state name
        DFReq <- cbind(hos_req, sta_req)
        DFReq
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, except change "v = v" into "v = num", which give a result  with NA in each cell. By the way, how do you add the code format in the comment here?

Comment: I don't know why, but after I run your code, my orginal function works too now. I will go back to check it again at another computer at home. And I will keep you posted.

Comment: As you said, it's the problem in the " for" loop, I can repeat my problem by change "V" into "num". Thank you very much.